# Model.findById is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

In main.js I invoke `driver.claimDropoff(myOrderId)` which looks like

```
const utils = require('../utils');
...
async claimDropoff(order) {
        order = await utils.ensureOrder(order);
        order.status = 1;
        order.dropoffDriver = this._id;
        await order.save()
        return this
    }
```

#### utils.js

```
const Order = require('./types/order');
...
async function ensureOrder(d) {
    d = (d.hasOwnProperty('_id')) ? d : await Order.findById(d);
    if (typeof d === 'undefined') { return new Error('Order not found') }
    return d;
}
```

#### types/order.js

```
...
const Driver = mongoose.model('Driver', DriverSchema, 'drivers');
module.exports = Driver;
```

My directory tree looks like this:

```
main.js
utils.js
|
└───types
    driver.js
    order.js
```

Yet I get the error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Order.findById is not a function`, which should not happen! I am requiring a mongoose.Model which should have a function `findById(id: any, callback: function)`

What causes this strange behaviour? Intellisense says that this is perfectly legal.

Comment: Does `Driver` imports `Order` and `Order` imports `Driver` ?

Comment: @AsafAviv your comment inspired the fix! Thank you so much :) I didn't do exactly that, but your comment got me thinking - infinite loops! It turns out I was importing `Order` in `utils` and `utils` in `Order`.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You should destructure the Order object.
Use it like this.

```
const { Order }= require('./types/order');
```